# App is on App Store but does not list in category

Tags: iphone, app-store, store, categories

We have an app on the store that if searched for by name or company it appears and we can download it, in fact it is getting downloaded, but it does not list in its category?

I have checked the iTunes Connect MetaData and it is in the category Education and is free, but if we list all free education apps it does not list.  We also looked to see if it would appear in the for sale listing just in case but does not.

Any body experienced this before?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but one about a problem with the App Store.  Perhaps if you asked at Apple's developer forums, they might be able to help you out: http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you just release it?  iTunes takes a while to refresh if it was just released.

Otherwise, I would consider looking at it's rankings on something like www.appannie.com (it's free to search for apps and view rankings) to see if it is seeing it also.

Otherwise, contact the appstore team